# can spring integration poll message after job is done when use with batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

For now the polling trigger can only be time based, but what I need is in batch when a job is finished, integration starts next polling. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Conditional Pollers for Message Sources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#conditional-pollers).

Or, use a `PollSkipAdvice`.

> AOP advice classes can be applied to pollers, in an advice-chain, such as a transaction advice to start a transaction. Starting with version 4.1, a PollSkipAdvice is provided. Pollers use triggers to determine the time of the next poll. The PollSkipAdvice can be used to suppress (skip) a poll, perhaps because there is some downstream condition that would prevent the message being processed. To use this advice, you have to provide it with an implementation of a PollSkipStrategy. Starting with version 4.2.5, a SimplePollSkipStrategy is provided. To use it, you can add an instance as a bean to the application context, inject it into a PollSkipAdvice, and add that to the poller’s advice chain. To skip polling, call skipPolls(). To resume polling, call reset(). Version 4.2 added more flexibility in this area. See Conditional Pollers for Message Sources.